# Sub that creates a chart which modifies itself based on a different selection of dataset

Tags: vba, excel

I want to code a sub that creates a chart from a 2 entries table giving the evolution of the number of inhabitants of 5 different cities every year. The row entry stays static (the years 1990 - 1991 - 1992 and so on), contrary to the column entry which represents the different cities.

I already wrote this code which does the job regarding the creation of the chart for each city one by one when I select one. Here is my code :

```
Sub DisplayChart()

    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim DataRange As Range

    Set DataRange = Selection
    Set MyChart = Sheets("Chart 1").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=DataRange
    MyChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

End Sub
```

However, I would like my chart to modify itself every time I select the data from another city (so every time I select a different row of data)

Thank you all in advance for your help !

Comment: Have you added filters to the table?  If you filter for a specific city name, the created chart *should* only display the visible data.  This allows looking at 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 cities at once.

Comment: Yes I know I can use filters but I want my macro to do so automatically

Comment: Not to be difficult, but that would automate the system pretty easily.  Just change the filter.  If you're looking to make a macro such that you can have CheckBoxes used, then you're either going to have to make a pivot table (inherently uses the checkbox/slicer situations) or place CheckBoxes, link them to data, and have said CheckBoxes add and remove data from the Chart when Checked.

Comment: @Sveta - look at creating a Pivot Table Chart.  I've done this with work centers and have the chart updating based on the work center(s) selected.  It works perfectly.  One thing I would caution you on though is checking the version of excel being used at the beginning of your chart creation routine and using the correct chart type variable for the version of excel, otherwise it may not run on different versions of excel